# Normal ordering for several operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I understand that if we consider a normal ordering of two operators
$\mathcal{N}(a_{p_1}a_{p_2}^{\dagger})$, it will be $a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_1}$,
where $a_{p_1}$ is an annihilation operator of a particle with a momentum $p_1$ and  $a_{p_2}^{\dagger}$ is a creation operator of a particle with momentum $p_2$.

But what about normal ordering for several operators? For example, let's consider
$\mathcal{N}(a_{p_1}a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_3}a_{p_4}^{\dagger}).$
Is it equal to
$$a_{p_4}^{\dagger}a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_1}a_{p_3},$$
or
$$a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_4}^{\dagger}a_{p_1}a_{p_3},$$
or
$$a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_4}^{\dagger}a_{p_3}a_{p_1},$$
or
$$a_{p_4}^{\dagger}a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_3}a_{p_1}?$$

Comment: Normally, all of the above since the a's commute among themselves and so do the a daggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal-ordering will always put annihilation operators on the right and creation operators on the left like you said. Creation and annihilation operators on each side will appear in the same order they were in before the application of the normal-ordering operator. So this case you have

$$ \mathcal{N}(a_{p_1}a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_3}a_{p_4}^{\dagger}) = a_{p_2}^{\dagger}a_{p_4}^{\dagger}a_{p_1}a_{p_3},$$

In the case of bosons you should note that it doesn’t make a difference since

$$[a_{p_1}, a_{p_2}] = [a_{p_1}^{\dagger}, a_{p_2}^{\dagger}] = 0 $$

Comment: It is simple when we have annihilation and creation operators. Is there a simple rule when you have position and momenta operators. of cours one can write it in terms of ladder operators, get the normal ordered formula and come back to position and momenta.....

Comment: Hello @Naima, sadly I have been away from QFT for a couple of years now so I will opt out of answering at the moment as I might not be very sure of my answer. Best wishes (Y)

Comment: Is is more complicated with x and $d_x$. if we have x x, we have to consider $(a+a^\dagger)(a+a^\dagger)$ and if we expanse it we see that x x is not normal ordered. we have to ADD things to it. and it becomes harder with x x x...